# How to enable numbers on bars in Bar chart

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to enable Numbers on each bar in Bar chart.

I am unable to find where I did mistake.

Note: Used sample-superstore data set.

I tried with below code I am getting error like "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'"

`   Grouped_data= df.groupby(['Region'],as_index=False).count()

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

barWidth = 0.9
x=np.arange(len(Grouped_data))
y=list(Grouped_data['Row ID'])
xx=list(Grouped_data['Region'])
plt.legend()
plt.bar(x,y,width = barWidth,color=['lime','r','k','tan'])
plt.xticks(x,xx,rotation=90)
label=y
for i in range(len(xx)):
    plt.text(x = xx[i]-0.5 , y = y[i]+0.1, s = label[i],size = 6)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom= 0.2, top = 0.98)
plt.show()
```

I want to see values on each bar in chart.

Comment: Mhh, not sure what would you say is the desired outcome of `"India" - 0.5`?

Comment: May be my code is wrong. So can you help me how we can achieve desire output. My desire outcome will be , need to see values on each bar. I mean East region Row Count(),Cental row count(),South and West Region row count() in bar chart with values on each bar.

Comment: The first comment contains a hint as to where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my condition, then i got desired outcome.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
plt.text(x = x[i]-0.2 , y = y[i]+0.1, s = label[i],size = 10)
```

[However need to place values to proper position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUKrT.png)